# How to convert Stream of Map into TreeMap in Java8

Tags: java, java-8

I have a method that takes in a Stream of map and should return a TreeMap

```
public TreeMap<String, String> buildTreeMap(Stream<Map<String, String>> inStream) {
   return stream.collect(toMap(???));
}
```

How can I make it return a TreeMap?

Comment: Sorry, for not making it clear, the method should return a TreeMap. I have updated the question.

Comment: The return type `TreeMap<Stream, Stream>` makes no sense…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
stream.collect(TreeMap::new, TreeMap::putAll, 
    (map1, map2) -> { map1.putAll(map2); return map1; });
```

...assuming you want to combine all the maps into one big map.

If you want different semantics for merging values for the same key, do something like

```
stream.flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
   .collect(toMap(
       Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (v1, v2) -> merge(v1, v2), TreeMap::new));
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this simply overwrites values in case of duplicate keys.

Answer (score 6):

Incase you're using a **groupingBy**,

```
 stream()
   .collect(
      Collectors.groupingBy(
        e -> e.hashCode(), TreeMap::new, Collectors.toList()))
```

where `e -> e.hashCode` is key function like `Entry::getKey`, `Student::getId`
and `Collectors.toList()` is `downstream` 
i.e what **datatype** you need as **value** in the tree map

This yields `TreeMap<Integer, List>`