# How to collect a stream into a TreeMap

Tags: java, java-stream, treemap

I know this is a noob a question, but I couldn't find a simpe answer anywhere else. Question is: I need to write a method that returns a `SortedMap`, so a tree map should work just fine. 
I have a `HashMap< String, Skill>`, the `Skill` class has both the methods `getName` and `getNumApplicants` and I need to return a `SortedMap<String, Long>`, with the name of the skill as a key and the number of applicants as value. This is where I stand:

```
private Map<String,Skill> skillMap = new HashMap<>();

public SortedMap<String, Long> skill_nApplicants() {

    return skillMap.values().stream().collect(...);
}
```

This is the Skill class

```
public class Skill {

    private String name;
    private List <Position> reqPosition = new ArrayList<>();
    private Long numApplicants;

    public void plusOneApplicant() {
        this.numApplicants++;
    }

    public Long getNumApplicants() {
        return numApplicants;
    }
    public Skill(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.numApplicants = 0L;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
        }

    public List<Position> getPositions() {
        return reqPosition;
        }
    public void addReqPosition(Position p) {
        this.reqPosition.add(p);
        return;
    }
}
```

I know this should be very easy, I just have a very hard time in understanding this all thing.

Comment: Quick question, what is the key of your `skillMap` map? You say that you have a `HashMap<Skill>` which is not correct. Also please post some more code.

Comment: skillMap<String,Skill>, this is the complete type of the map.

Comment: And they key? What does your key represent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31660900/how-to-convert-stream-of-map-into-treemap-in-java8 ?

Comment: Similar question, but in that case the solution involves returning a map of maps, I only need to insert a single value

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Don't collect the data to a `HashMap` first, *then* convert to a `TreeMap`. Collect the data directly to a `TreeMap` by using the overloaded [`toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, mergeFunction, mapSupplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) method that allows you to specify which `Map` to create (4th parameter).

```
public SortedMap<String, Long> skill_nApplicants() {
    return skillMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Skill::getName,
            Skill::getNumApplicants,
            Math::addExact, // only called if duplicate names can occur
            TreeMap::new
    ));
}
```

Comment: Is there a function that omits the merger function but specifies the map supplier?

Comment: @francescofoschi No. Which you could see for yourself in the javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#i32

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do it

```
public SortedMap<String, Long> skill_nApplicants(Map<String, Skill> skillMap) {
    Map<String, Long> result = skillMap.values().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Skill::getName, Skill::getNumApplicants));
    return new TreeMap<>(result);
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, maybe I'll change it to
        public SortedMap<String, Long> skill_nApplicants(Map<String, Skill> skillMap) {
    Map<String, Long> result = skillMap.values().stream().sorted(comparing(Skill::getName)).collect(Collectors.toMap(Skill::getName, Skill::getNumApplicants));
    return new TreeMap<>(result);
}

Comment: If name or numApplicants values are null, you will get NullPointerException

Comment: I tried your solution in eclipse and it does not allow the cast to TreeMap

Comment: You should use JDK8, I have test it locally before sending you the answer and it is working. Not need to cast.

Comment: I have JDK8 running this is the error : "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.TreeMap
 at applications.HandleApplications.skill_nApplicants(HandleApplications.java:140)"

Comment: I omitted the "new" after return, now it works, thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Select the answer as valid answer if you can, thanks.

Comment: you're constructing 2 maps with this one, see the best answer for collecting directly into the treemap

Answer (score 2):

If, in your stream, you don't have two (or more) values which should be mapped with the same key, then you can avoid to use a Collector at all (and thus you don't need to think about a merge function).

All you need to do is to simply add each skill to the map with a `forEach`:

```
public SortedMap<String, Long> skill_nApplicants() {
    Map<String, Long> result = new TreeMap<>();
    
    skillMap.values()
        .forEach((skill) -> result.put(skill.getName(), skill.getNumApplicants());
        
    return result;
}
```

You can wrap `result` with [`Collections.unmodifiableSortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSortedMap-java.util.SortedMap-) if you want to return an unmodifiable map.